# Mark my question as community wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

I searched for an answer to a question with google, and the in-site search, and was unable to find a post here.

So I posted a question. Once I was finished, I found a related question, with no upvotes, no accepted answer.

I believe that make it reasonable to keep my question, as well as the original - so future readers can find an answer.

I have marked my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929268/adb-shell-am-with-double-value) as a duplicate of ([Broadcasting and receiving extra doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730386/broadcasting-and-receiving-extra-doubles)).

I don't think mine should be deleted, but will leave that up to Android mods. However if it does stay around, there's no point getting rep off it - so can someone mark it as community wiki for me pls?

---

I did flag for moderator attention, to own up to a duplicate, and request it not get deleted. In that flag I said I would mark it as Community Wiki.

But I could not do that myself as there is no checkbox for questions.

And I can't flag the same post twice. Hence this post - to get some diamond attention.

Comment: In future, just flag the question as needing moderator attention, and explain why you want it to be CW'd; they're the only people who can do this.

Comment: Why do you want it marking CW?

Comment: @chrisF I just didn't want to look like I was fishing for rep by leaving it available for upvotes.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier - you asked it in good faith so there's no reason not to get rep for it (assuming it's otherwise a good question)

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for giving the immediate duplicate vote for me. Should I delete this meta post?

Comment: Up to you, but it might be useful to have in case someone else is is the same position.

Comment: I'll leave it here then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicates aren't automatically deleted.

If it was to be deleted it would have to be done by user/moderator action and while that's not impossible I don't believe it will be likely.

Comment: Ok, well that's good news. I think even though its a duplicate it will help future searches on a rather arcane question.